# Unique element with minimal norm in closed convex subset

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I have shown that for $X$ a hilbert space, $K$ a non empty closed convex subset of $X,$ that $K$ admits a unique element of minimal norm.

I am now looking for an example of a Banach space where this is not necessairily true, ie what is an example of a Banach space $Y$ such that for $M$ a closed convex subset of $Y,$ there does not exist a unique element in $M$ with minimal norm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $X=\mathbb R^2$ endowed with the $\infty$-norm and set $K:=[-1,1]\times\{1\}$. It is clear that all the elements of $K$ have distance $1$ from the origin, i.e. they all are minimal in norm.

Notice that more in general every norm such that its unit sphere contains a straight line (that is, a non strictly convex norm) can provide a similar example.

Comment: Ah it was so obvious and I missed it. Thank you!